# How to help translating the wallet?

Tags: mist, wallets

I'm interested in doing translations for my language. I've seen there are Ukraine and German translations available for mist.

I'd like to begin, but don't know about any resources to start with. In shorter words, I'd like to know what is available to translate and where the resources are. And how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Translations are always welcome, though they also make it harder to change texts later on, as they have to be changed in all those added languages :)

The Ethereum wallet consists currently of two repos, the Mist browser repo and the ethereum wallet. You need to translate both, but for now i would like to see only the wallet being translated, as Mist lang files will likely change a lot over time.

You would need to translate these two files (`mist/wallet.lang.i18n.json` and `app.lang.i18n.json`) and save them with your language lang code in:
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/tree/develop/interface/i18n
https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/tree/develop/app/i18n

Then create a PR to this repositories, so we can check the differences.
Additionally you would need to add you language to this file:
https://github.com/ethereum/meteor-dapp-wallet/blob/develop/app/project-tap.i18n
https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/develop/interface/project-tap.i18n

If you want to test you language, start Mist in development mode (see here: https://github.com/ethereum/mist)

And open the browser console (CMD/CTRL + ALT + i) and type `TAPi18n.setLanguage('xx')`